# New Flutter project creation in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Why can't I create a new Flutter project in *VSCode*? Each time I run the, 'flutter create project name'* it says Flutter is not recognized. I have both Flutter and Dart extensions installed.

```
flutter : The term 'flutter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ flutter create agregatorpro
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Do you have have the Flutter SDK downloaded and unzipped? Have you configured the location of the SDK on VSCode?

Comment: Make sure it's added to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `where flutter` in cmd: It should give path to flutter sdk, and if it is not so then add `'your_path'/flutter/bin` (here 'your path' is where you extracted flutter in: commonly it is `C:/src`) in your environment variables.

Then run `flutter doctor` once flutter is recognized..